# android tab layout listview not clickable

Tags: android, android-listview, android-tabhost

i have implemented a tab layout that consists of four tabs each tab containing a listview. i was using the same setup of listview earlier but not under tab host and it worked fine, ie; when a list item was clicked a new activity would start. but now the list is neither clickable not scrollable.how ever now, when i click all the tabs once and then try to scroll/click rows, it works perfectly fine.  please let me know how do i enable both. the code is as below

```
tabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        tabHost.setup();
        tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(this);

        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listAll);
        list.setEmptyView((TextView) findViewById(R.id.empty));

        //list for all

        tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec(LIST_ALL).setIndicator("All Events").setContent(new TabContentFactory() {
            public View createTabContent(String arg0) {
                try{
                    Event event = new Event();
                    final String [] eventTitleArray = new String[XmlParser.eventsList.size()];
                    String [] eventDateArray = new String[XmlParser.eventsList.size()];
                    String [] eventImageLinkArray = new String[XmlParser.eventsList.size()];

                for(int i=0;i<XmlParser.eventsList.size();i++){
                        event = XmlParser.eventsList.get(i);
                        eventTitleArray[i] = event.getTitle();
                        if(event.getDistance()!=0.0)
                            eventDateArray[i] = event.getsDate() +" - " +Double.toString(event.getDistance())+"mi";
                        else
                            eventDateArray[i] = event.getsDate();
                        eventImageLinkArray[i] = event.getImageLink();


                        Log.i(tag , "event detail"+event.getTitle());
                    }
                    list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listAll);
                    adapter= new LazyAdapter(HomeActivity.this, eventTitleArray,eventDateArray,eventImageLinkArray);
                    list.setAdapter(adapter);
                    list.setFocusable(false);
                    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                                int position, long arg3) {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, DisplayActivity.class);
                            Bundle b = new Bundle();
                            System.out.println("position in list:"+position);
                            System.out.println("title name in the list:"+eventTitleArray[position]);
                            b.putString("eventTitle", eventTitleArray[position]);
                            intent.putExtras(b);
                            startActivity(intent);

                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Detailed view for the Event", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                        }
                    });
                }
                catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return list;
            }
        }));

        tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec(LIST_TODAY).setIndicator("Events Today").setContent(new TabContentFactory() {
            public View createTabContent(String arg0) {
                return list;
            }
        }));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just did this and the list works perfectly fine now.

```
        tabHost.setCurrentTab(3);
        tabHost.setCurrentTab(2);
        tabHost.setCurrentTab(1);
        tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the ListView marked as clickable in your Layout XML file?

It should look something like this:

```
<ListView 
       android:id="@+id/MyListView" 
       android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:clickable="true"/>
```

Comment: am sorry but you have not mentioned how it should look like? also, please read the question again, i just added some more valuable information

Comment: That was strange; the text was in my response but didn't render for some reason.

Comment: thanks...but did you read my question again..i added some information in it. the list is clickable/scrollable but only after the last widget is clicked